# 1 down vote on every question and answer seems like abuse from 1 person

Tags: support

Receltly, i joined stack overflow and asked my first question. I got an answer and was happy. No downvotes. After asking more questions I still never got a downvote. After asking a question marked as duplicate, I noticed that I had a lot of profile views and someone continuously downvotes my older qusetions/answers 1 or 2 per day. Those questions are too old to be on the questions page, which means that someone had to view my account and then access them from there. I don't like the fact that I'm on he edge of being blocked from asking questions. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: There are scripts running to detect serial down voting. So the system already takes care of it. You can consider editing your older posts and improving them.

Comment: I've just gone through your rep history, it seems as though there was one user that DV'ed two of your posts simultaneously (only 33 secs between each DV), besides that the rest look genuine.

Comment: [Your](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24227868/2982225) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24219774/2982225) need improvement. These are like generic comments. I would suggest editing and improving.

Comment: @Sam As short as [some of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219732/where-can-i-found-qt-5-3-0-command-prompt/24219774#24219774) are, 33 seconds is not necessarily an unreasonable amount of time to read and cast a vote. Those votes are likely legitimate as well.

Comment: @CodyGray Good point, I didn't realise how short they were.

Comment: Possible better duplicate: [Stealth revenge-downvoter: a downvote a day keeps the reversal-script away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308502)

Answer (score 6):

Serial downvoting will be identified by the system.  If that is the case, it will undo the damage to your rep.

Comment: what if the person is only downvoting my posts once a day (which can bypass the serial voting limit) ?

Comment: @Wolfdog How do you know it's the same person? Most likely, it's different people then.

Comment: how can i find out?

Comment: @Wolfdog Unfortunately votes are anonymous. So there's no way (that I know of) to see if it's a single user is behind the DVs.

Comment: You could ask the SE people to investigate abuse thru the "contact us" link in the footer.

Comment: @Wolfdog Np; actually there is one possible way, if you noticed the downvotes starting to happen within 5 mins or so of each other, then it's most likely a single user.

Comment: @Wolfdog if you think someone may be actively targeting you, then flag one of your posts and use the Other flag, and explain the situation to a moderator. They have tools to see if someone has been consistently downvoting another user, and may take appropriate action to fix the problem.

Comment: @Payeli I guess I should have been more specific, my suggestion of 5 minutes was on the assumption that the Q/A wasn't newly posted (maybe even 5 mins is too much), keep forgetting the OP's new here.

Comment: @Cupcake I flagged my question and asked for help. Thank you cupcake (the way Trevor from GTA5 says it). But shouldn't I ask the support team for help rather than moderators?

Comment: @Wolfdog it's a moderators job to handle this sort of thing, and if they need to, they'll escalate the issue to Stack Exchange support employees.

Comment: You say that serial down-voting will be identified: the goal is to address revenge voting. But it feels like there's a new type of down-voting trend, where someone doesn't like a question for some reason and downvotes the question and all of its answers. It's a different problem and the system doesn't catch it.