# Stealth revenge-downvoter: a downvote a day keeps the reversal-script away

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes, serial-voting

The last few days I've been getting seemingly random downvotes on my questions, but I've worked out that it's likely the same user doing it.

Here is my reputation history for the last few days:

[image]
<sup>(The above image has been edited to remove irrelevant information)</sup>

I think it is the same user doing it because:

- Every downvote was made at around the same time each day (so if I *am* being targeted, the downvoter might be doing it on their lunch break);
- I've recently had a disagreement with a couple of users here on Meta (where their answers were later deleted)
- There's only a pattern of one downvote a day (in contrast if someone's sharing my questions it'd be likely that it would attract *more* than one downvote)
- I've never got downvotes in this capacity before, and the random start to 'a downvote a day' is suspicious in itself.

I've checked and there isn't anything wrong with the questions themselves, *but* however they are basic and the answers to them are simple.

I can't decide if this is enough to warrant a Stack Exchange employee to have a closer look into this, or if I should simply flag one of the downvoted questions explaining my suspicions. Of course, posting this question *might* help, but then again, it might not.

I read [Who do I go to when I'm being stalked by a specific user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308265/who-do-i-go-to-when-im-being-stalked-by-a-specific-user), but if I don't know/have proof that a specific user is doing it, or if I'm even being targeted, should I follow the same steps as a precaution?

> We can only see larger patterns, though, and cannot see individual
>   votes. Stack Exchange employees need to be called in to investigate
>   and invalidate these votes, and their time is very limited. We tend to
>   call them in only in the worst or most obvious cases.

I don't want to waste the valuable time of a Stack Exchange employee to investigate this if I can't be sure if I'm even being targeted.

Is it worth bringing this to a moderator or Stack Exchange employee?

Looks like it's still happening, and that the pattern has changed. Now in the morning & one of those was on a +14/-0 answer of mine which has nothing wrong.
**It seems that whoever's behind this is well-aware of this Meta post**:

[image]

Comment: Flag one of your own posts and ask a mod to look into the matter. No need for a meta post.

Comment: @Boann the OP isn't asking for any action to be taken, they are asking for guidance on what to do in this kind of situation. I'm fairly certain that is a valid reason for a meta post.

Comment: @Boann I'm asking what to do in this situation, as mods are unable to view individual votes for a post.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227845/168933 as well.

Comment: If you find a solution under the current system please let me know. My suggestion on a comment below is an exponential backoff in how long before you can next downvote the same person. But that would require getting the powers that be to agree.

Comment: @Sammy If you think it's a good idea, then create a new Meta post requesting the feature. Saying that, votes are already rate-limited & I think the system is fine as it is, just that some people like to game the system by trying to get around it.

Comment: How many days before he brings you down to zero rep?

Comment: @SalmanA Infinite days, since rep can't go below 1. Assuming that's what you meant, and assuming bob gains no more rep, and assuming the culprit is not stopped, it will take 848 days.

Comment: @TylerH thats my point. Let them waste 848 days of their life.

Comment: @SalmanA It's not really a waste if their goal is to reduce bob's reputation unfairly and cause him undue stress/harassment, which seems to be the case judging by the fact that bob was moved to ask on Meta about it.

Comment: @SalmanA the logic is flawed. You are assuming the culprit has enough questions to downvote. OP only has so many questions and answers, and each is worth more than 2 rep on average, so the most the culprit can achieve is quite limited, or -2 per question/answer.

Comment: StackOverflow is a game if and only if you think it is. I get gratuitous, commentless downvotes for answers I wrote 5 years ago. I used to be tempted to take umbrage at it but concluded that life is too short for that. I've also received daily, seemingly retaliatory downvotes. Often such users would implode or rage-quit and all their votes got invalidated. Don't fret so, it's only rep points.

Comment: I want to know how the story continues. It's now two days later than the date of your screenshot, so... did you receive two more downvotes since?

Comment: The bigger question is should we be able to see the downvotes?

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Viewing vote counts (downvotes + upvotes) is a privilege that you'll get when you hit 1,000 reputation.

Comment: (I know the question is old but) is it reversed?

Comment: @user202729 In my case I had to get an SE employee involved.. was resolved extremely quickly.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

> Is it worth bringing this to a moderator or Stack Exchange employee?

That's up to you. If it's not particularly bothering you, then you could just take satisfaction in the belief that someone is slowly wasting their life on this and go spend your own doing something more productive.

But if it's sticking in your craw, then flag a post & ask a moderator to have a look. They can probably determine whether or not this is really an issue fairly quickly, and will cheerfully tell you to go do something else if there's no reason to be concerned. If there's a real problem, they'll escalate.

Comment: Just an idea for your script: Track if there is a user which got more downvotes then the average user who got downvotes yet from the downvoter. So if you downvote regularly you will have properbly not more then 3 downvotes per user. That slow downvoter will reach a higher level e.g. 6 which is double then all other downvoted persons. Edit: But please don't use this for upvotes, remember users like Jon Skeet, you proberbly upvotes some more answers of him then the avg user.

Comment: @rekire: Problem with that is if users A and B both monitor a given tag and A is clueless/repwhoring/whatever and routinely posting unuseful answers, B will routinely see them and correctly downvote them. The script would flag that up even though B's actions are correct. 'Tis complicated...

Comment: Just happened again on two more of my posts, will email SE later today. Could just be drive-by downvotes, but I'm pretty sure there isn't a valid reason for a +14 answer of mine to suddenly get a single downvote- it seems that whoever's doing it **is well aware of this Meta post.**

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there are other people around in this community that could down vote. No one requires a personal nemesis to keep their answers clean.

Comment: @Sammy: There's an important distinction between being a nemesis (which requires malice) and just downvoting bad answers without regard to who posts them. If you hang out in some of the tags I do, you see a *lot* of poor answers. Impossible to keep a mental tally of how often you've seen bad answers from user A and say "Oh dear, I'd best not downvote this poor content so the script doesn't mistake me for a nemesis." More to the point: Why should you? It's the *answer*, not the *person*, that you're downvoting. As it should be.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you get blocked because you've exceed your downvote limit on that user, it encourages you to speak up and tell them why their answers are lousy via a comment. That's much more useful both to the offending user and the community. It's entirely possibly that user is genuinely clueless and needs to fix their answers in some particular way. -1 just tells you someone didn't like what you said, not why.

Comment: @Sammy: I never said anything about not leaving a comment, not that leaving a comment is necessary in all cases. Also don't get the impression I run around downvoting stuff; frequently I comment without downvoting stuff willy-nilly. But that's everyone's own choice to make. Plenty of answers that need downvoting are so obviously and completely "try this" rubbish and similar that a downvote without comment is an entirely appropriate action. All of which *beside the point*. A script that flags up correct behavior as incorrect is a broken script.

Comment: _"A script that flags up correct behavior as incorrect is a broken script."_ - To expand on that: _"Then comment instead"_ is not a valid workaround.

Comment: Apologies, *"Also don't get the impression I run around downvoting stuff; frequently I comment without downvoting stuff willy-nilly"* was meant to read *"Also don't get the impression I run around downvoting stuff  willy-nilly; frequently I comment without downvoting."* :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Peace friend. I didn't mean to imply or accuse you of being a troll. People who have honest debates in meta generally aren't the ones you need to worry about.

Comment: @Cerbrus You comment. Others will see the comment, understand, and some will downvote. I don't think it would break the system at all.

Comment: @Sammy: Because everyone reads the comments on a post before leaving the page. Because comments also have an effect on the order in which posts are shown. Because comments also allow a post to be deleted after a certain amount of negativity. I repeat. _"Then comment instead"_ is ___not a valid workaround.___ Comments and votes are ___completely___ unrelated. You're saying apples are an alternative for pear-shaped spacecrafts.

Comment: @Cerbrus Mods will read the comments. Anyone interested in using the solution when they come across it later will read the comments. People who want to vote SHOULD read the comments. These are the groups that matter.

Comment: @Sammy: Don't be so naïve. There's way too much content on SO for comments to be a good alternative to votes. Downvotes have a _lot_ of automated repercussions. _none_ of those repercussions are based on comments. All of that would have to be done manually by a _staff_ member that would have to _see_ the comment in the first place. If a user continuously posts bad content, comments aren't going to get him answer banned. Downvotes resulting in deletion will.

Comment: @Sammy: Don't worry, I didn't get the impression you were calling me a troll. :-)

Comment: @rekire: Sorry, I should have said: I'm not saying I wouldn't want *something* done, somehow, if possible. And good on you for trying. The behavior the OP is describing is harmful to the site (and just generally jerky). :-) It'd be worth running an analysis to see if the false positives I describe happen enough to make the script unusable, or if there are few enough that mods can weed out those false positives without too much effort (since I'm thinking the output of the script could reveal high-level details on the votes so that mods rather than SE employees could triage).

Comment: "...take satisfaction in the belief that someone is slowly wasting his life on this and go spend your own doing something more productive. " Nicely said.  Applies to trolls in all parts of life.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I know you had this conversation almost a year ago, but I'd like to add that in most tags with healthy amounts of traffic, if user A is habitually posting unuseful answers, it's likely that users B, C, D, E and so on will all show up in downvotes towards A. Assuming we rule out the possibility of a voting ring (which [*has* happened](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313743/action-for-unreasonable-downvotes/313770#313770), needless to say), that's pretty damning if you ask me :)

Comment: @BoltClock: Big time. :-)

Comment: @Shog9, If I flag my post, then it says "12 flags remaining" so it will not work until 12 others report something??!

Comment: That's 12 flags for the day that *you* have remaining (in your "inventory" so to speak; you can raise them on other posts if need-be). Just one is fine for getting a moderator's attention, @Black.

Comment: @Shog9, aaah, now I understand.

Answer (score -36):

As I have said before, this is essentially an [unsolvable problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298063).

People are allowed to downvote you, the problem comes when downvotes are being
targeted at a person rather than posts. So the obvious question is, where do we
drawn the line? Let us use a [binary search algorithm](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#One-sided_search) to decide:

- Downvote every hour -> targeting user
- 2 hours -> user
- 4 hours -> user
- 8 hours -> user
- 16 hours -> user
- 1 day -> ?
- 2 days -> ?

Here is the problem with your complaint. Right now we have this post:

> Someone is downvoting me every day, make them stop!

Now if we change the script to 2 days, we get this:

> Someone is downvoting me every 2 days, make them stop!

ad infinitum. I think the current system is fine as is. Even if someone is
downvoting you every day, it is a trifle. Even with your low rep, look at the
numbers:

2 points / 1674 point = 0.001

That is 1/10 of 1% of your rep. If you get even one answer upvote, it just
knocked out 5 days worth of “work” from your “nemesis”. Let it go man.

Comment: Overall the "don't worry about rep" point is solid, but the frustration of having a -1 _score_ on an answer that you are pretty sure is caused by someone not liking _you_ personally is understandable.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I like Reddit’s approach to this, they let you vote for yourself. So you can at least start every answer with one vote. I think it would need tweaking if we adopted that though, as an answer upvote here is 10 points vs 1 there

Comment: @StevenPenny And then, everybody will do it, and the effect is gone anyway. A Reddit post with score 0 is probably as frustrating as having a SO answer at -1.

Comment: I would wager that the lost rep is irrelevant for a regular SO poster. That guy would have to waste almost a year or more giving you downvotes to take away 1k rep, which is like what, two to three weeks of activity? The more frustrating part of this is that solid answers in low frequency tags that really could help someone out get downvoted and get less visible due to that.

Comment: That's not what I was asking...

Comment: How about an exponential backoff.
No user is permitted to downvote any other single user more than
once in the last day, twice in the last 2 days, 3 times in the last 4 days, 
4 times in the last 8 days, 5 times in the last 16 days, 6 times in the last 32 days and so on. Makes it a waste of time for trolls to keep track.
3 d

Comment: @Sammy Wouldn't work, it would just encourage 'downvote parties'.

Comment: @bob That would still require more coordination and effort than a single person deciding to trash another person's work. Any system can be defeated. It's just a matter of making it a little harder. This one's a hole wide open in my opinion. It's totally trivial to game the system as it stands.

Comment: @Sammy It would just frustrate users.

Comment: @bob Any user who goes around downvoting good answers needs to be frustrated. Any good user will also understand that they can comment instead of vote. I don't think votes should be anonymous either. If you want to say someone else's work is bad, you should have to have to put your name behind it. Too many people troll given power without accountability.

Comment: @Sammy: I see users in JavaScript that regularly post low quality answers. Those limitations won't work.

Comment: @Cerbrus given that you still are seeing those answers "regularly" how about you tell those users exactly why the answers are low quality. Because if it's regular the current system isn't working very well. -1 just says someone didn't like it, not why or in what way they are bad. The users that are providing bad answers for selfish reasons get shown up, and those that don't know why their answers are bad get an opportunity to improve or refute your argument about why the answer is bad.

Comment: @Sammy: I did comment, time and time again. Don't assume I just drive-by vote. They usually delete the answer, and find a different trivial question to misinterpret. My point is that rate-limiting votes on users like that is counter-productive.

Comment: I don't understand your argument. Time doesn't go "ad infinitum". Once you set the time-span to a life-time the problem disappears completely and for now that time-span is limited to a century or so.

Comment: Percentage of rep lost isn't harsh. Threat of an eventual answer ban is.

Comment: @Sammy, I think it would be nice if you had to be held accountable for your votes, but it could easily cause tension between users when they find out who is downvoting them.