# Action for Unreasonable Downvotes

Tags: support, voting, moderation

I got 123 reputations this day, until this afternoon. Then I've come across questions which I and others downvoted and commented because they are not appropriate for the community being asked.  (around 3 questions)
My reputation rating was still nice since a question of mine was downvoted because of a title problem. It was a -2 reputation. so I got 121. But I was surprised when I refreshed the whole page, then I saw my reputation drop down to 77. Then another refresh to see if it is only a bug, it only got worse, to 53 rep. Finally, I got 21 rep right now. 
I do not know what's happening, but the question which are downvoted are 5 days to 2 weeks old, and are answered without downvotes.

My concern is, should it really be like that? That when you downvote or comment on a question which deserves one, others will revenge and try to drop your rep as low as they can? If it isn't, can any action be taken against these?

Thanks. I'm new to asking in meta, so pardon me if I am not that familiar with the tags that I should use for this question.

Comment: If you've had a large number of down votes from a single person, it's likely they will get reversed tomorrow morning.

Comment: I've already sent a ticket @TZHX. I just thought of posting it here so others who may have the same issue in the future may find this.

Comment: Sending a ticket is pointless -- just let the automated system take care of it.

Comment: Just to note - mods are looking into this now - as *something* is going on...

Comment: It's really best not to assume or assert "revenge" without very, very strong evidence. But you've drawn attention to what does seem a surprising reputation drop at first glance and you can hope that a moderator will dig deeper to see what the reasons are.

Comment: Looks like socks downvoting. Mods already dealing with it. Very possible that this came to their attention through their tools already. Someone is going to regret doing that. Flagging for attention on this was a good idea, as it is not a "normal" single user doing it.

Comment: That voting *should* be anonymous, like it is in any democracy, instead of having to be explained in a comment is something that has to be learned sometimes.  You got a lesson.  That using multiple accounts, voting in anger and targeting a user does not work is somebody else's lesson to learn today :)

Comment: @NickCox I do have. I just don't understand what happened. I hav downvoted questions which I asked 3 days after I started using stackoverflow. I'm at 1st month now.

Comment: Note that after the reversals you do have some genuine downvotes. Avoid, like the plague, answering typo questions. They are no future benefit to anyone, just flag them for closure, there's a specific off-topic reason (read all the text and you'll find it). I'd delete that answer.

Comment: Sorry that you had to experience this. You were targeted by a particularly coordinated voting ring in an attempt to attack you. Most of these users will find they no longer have an account on this site as a result, because this is an egregious abuse of the voting system.

Comment: all that started from a simple comment? wow..... where you insulting, attacking, or anything? because wow...

Comment: I wasn't. @Patrice

Comment: @Cyval wow.... some people really have a short fuse then :/.... so much gripe and resentment and downright abuse of the system for ONE comment.... sheesh :( Sorry you had to go through such a bad experience :(

Comment: While I appreciate the problem here, there was zero reason to reopen this post - serial downvoting happens and the linked duplicate covers it for virtually all users who experience the issue (especially when multiple mods already commented to say it was being/had been dealt with.

Comment: @psubsee2003 As it was pointed out by Brad, that wasn't a typical case of serial voting by a single user. Thats the reason why I've been retracting my dupe close vote, and voted to reopen later on.

Comment: @BradLarson I would appreciate if you put your comment as an answer. That wasn't a typical serial downvoting case, and might not have been corrected by the automatically running scripts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ regardless, the answer in the dup would address this question.  I still don't think we need another question for this "special case".... `but if in the unlikely event it doesn't clear them all wait 24 hours and should any suspicious down-votes remain flag one of the posts for moderator attention using the "other" option and explain what happened.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My concern is, should it really be like that? That when you downvote or comment on a question which deserves one, others will revenge and try to drop your rep as low as they can? If it isn't, can any action be taken against these?

No, revenge voting is never OK. Action can be taken when there is overwhelming evidence of an attack.

As other moderators who investigated your case have indicated, this was indeed a coordinated attack. Worse still, by multiple accounts. Whether these belonged to a single person or someone rallied his lackeys we don't know for sure, but it's deplorable either way. The offending accounts have been dealt with and your lost reputation restored.

I hope we've helped make New Year's Eve a little better for you. Happy new year.

Comment: Happy new year, and keep up the good fight!

Comment: Great, BoltClock! That's really a good one to celebrate all of our efforts at new year's eve. Happy new year everyone.

Comment: Should I create a meta post if the system didn't reverse a series of revenge downvotes?

Comment: @Mederic: No; flag one of your affected posts instead and we'll ask someone to look into it.