# How to deal with users who regularly put minimal effort into answers?

Tags: discussion

Always when I check out some questions there're one or two answers from one specific user. Nearly always their answers are some phrases like *"You can do it as follows:"*, followed by code-pasta. I've noticed that they often "copy" other answers, which were already present, and just post. Doing some changes here and there but posting essentially the same thing.

I don't remember the last time I've seen an answer from them that is not a duplicate under the same question or a low-quality code-writing-service. The user often, if not always, answers very simple-to-answer questions from new users. I very rarely see answers from that user that go deeper into something. Not rarely other users have to leave a comment to point out mistakes.

I know that such numbers don't have much value but still kinda say a bit about the account: They have 850 posts with a score of around 450. So they have an average score of 0.5 on each answer. They have only around 5 questions and 2/3 of the answers are at 0 score. The account was created around 1 year ago. Just some numbers to give you an idea.

I think that this person is only interested in reputation for their online image. And I think that most of their posts are literally formally-correct spam. And I think that they are posting under questions that already got correct answers for reputation and not to add anything meaningful.

I mean, I know that this is all greyzone, most likely completely legit, but I still think that this is not a good thing: A user who posts minimal-effort answers for reputation. Noone is putting 100 % effort into every answer but this user is next level. Is there any mechanism that prevents something like this on Stack Overflow?

<sub>To be clear, by "copy" I don't mean that they are CTRL-C'&'CTRL-V'ing answers but essentially writing the same thing while being aware of the other answers.</sub>

Comment: There are. How many of that person's answers are you downvoting? For the automated systems to kick in (bans and such), there needs to be some signal for the system to know it should act.

Comment: Realistically the only option for person with so many posts is to flag for moderator interventions... While downvoting as @Patrice said indeed is a good idea but for case you describe you may easily run into "serial downvotes" land...

Comment: Use your votes. If an answer is not helpful, vote it down. If it is useful, vote it up. If you feel you can write a better answer, write that better answer! No, moderators will not intervene in cases like these because the user is doing nothing wrong. They are just not doing it _right_ either.

Comment: However, if there is a pattern of *plagiarism*, copying the work of others, please flag those posts. That is something moderators *do* act on! See [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071). Note that writing the same answer without outright copy-pasting, within the first hour or so the question has been posted, is usually not plagiarism.

Comment: @Patrice Unless someone's average answer score is in danger of being negative, *or* some of their answers get deleted from review (which sounds quite unlikely to be happening in this situation), I don't think there's any chance of an automatic low-quality ban - which makes sense. Here, downvoting such posts will help inform the poster and others that it isn't useful, but it won't lead to more consequences.

Comment: Since @MartijnPieters said flagging is wrong here than really nothing going to happen... [Downvote a day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308502/stealth-revenge-downvoter-a-downvote-a-day-keeps-the-reversal-script-away) may make you feel doing your part.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It doesn't bother me enough to do something like that but I will definitely downvote him when I see the next garbage posts from him.

Comment: I don't see how guessing the motives of the users helps the conversation any. Why does it matter why the user answers in the way they do? What matters is the content of the answers. As others have said, vote on the usefulness of the content.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Downvote and move on.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend skipping any trackable interaction (like comment) if one plans to downvote...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Delete the comments if they say no.

Comment: "get rid of all traces of the conversation" why?

Comment: @JonasWilms So the user can't go back and argue with you or get revenge.

Comment: just don't downvote _all_ the posts from this person, or you'll be the one violating the rules.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Of course not. Just the ones that you see that contain only code and the aforementioned "Try this:" sentences.